# Vue 3 + ts Login

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, supabase

Not long ago got acquainted with such technology as Supabase and everywhere all write registration on js why can not on ts.
I started to make vue 3 + ts and met such errors help to solve them.
The "user" property does not exist in the type "{ data: { user: User | null; session: Session | null; }; error: null; }".
The "user" property does not exist in the "AuthResponse" type.
"error" refers to the type unknown.

**the subase.ts file is spelled correctly and everything is downloaded.**

It's my code:

```
<template>
  <div class="container-login">
    <h1>Test Form</h1>
    <div class="inputContainer">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" v-model="email" />
    </div>

    <div class="inputContainer">
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" v-model="password" />
    </div>

    <div class="inputContainer">
      <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="firstName" v-model="firstName" />
    </div>

    <div class="buttonContainer">
      <button @click="createAccount">Create Account</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { supabase } from '../supabase';

const email = ref('');
const password = ref('');
const firstName = ref('');

async function createAccount() {
  try {
    const { user, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
      email: email.value,
      password: password.value,
    });

    if (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    } else {
      // Additional information can be updated after successful registration
      await supabase.from('users').upsert([
        {
          id: user?.id,
          email: email.value,
          first_name: firstName.value,
        },
      ]);

      console.log('Registration successful:', user);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
}

</script>
```

I tried everything supabase itself does not support ts strange a lot of videos watched all on js is done I do not understand

Answer (score 2):

from reading the doc, the top level property returned is called data in their example.

```
const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
    email: 'example@email.com',
    password: 'example-password',
})
```

so as the both the type and error suggests user is not a valid property being returned from the signUp method, it is a property of data. User can be accessed via data?.user

https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-signup